# Exporting Team Project from tfs server

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Is there any way of exporting Team Project or Team Project Collection from Team Foundation Server 2015 to tfs 2012?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You tagged this with TFS2010, 2012, 2013, **and** VS Team Services. Which one is it? The answer differs depending on which you're actually using.

Comment: Hi, Daniel. My mistake, I edited my question.

Answer (score 4):

You can't downgrade Team Project Collection databases. There is no mechanism to move Team Projects between collections at all, even within the same instance of TFS.

Depending on your exact requirements, there may be a third party tool that is capable of migrating some of the data (work items, source code, etc), but not with full fidelity.

Answer (score 0):

[There](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) is the tool to migrate data between TFS that you can try to use and check the result.